# How do I take out the 2 or more-digit numbers in a python string?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to add up the numbers in the string like such: 76 977
I need to add up these numbers, but I get a 1st+2nd digit sum.

My code:

```
a = list(input())
a.remove(' ')
print(a)
print(int(a[0])+int(a[1]))
```

Comment: The remove method returns a new string, because they're immutable. And then you're using the first and second _characters_. Also note https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3001761

Comment: 1. Is there space in the string, like `76 977` ? 2. Do you want to add `76` and `977` or sum of all the digits ?

Comment: @NileshBhave 76+977

Comment: When you remove the space from the input, you get `76977`. `a[0]` and `a[1]` will give you the first two digits in the string - 7 and 6, and that's why you get the sum of the first two digits.

Answer (score 0):

use the **split** function:

```
a = "76 977"
b=a.split(" ")
sum = 0
for num in b:
    sum += int(num)
print(sum)
```

Comment: `sum(map(int, b))`

Answer (score 0):

Try `a.split(' ')`, it takes a string and returns a list of strings seperated by that string.

```
a = input()
b = a.split(' ')
print(b)
print(int(b[0])+int(b[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different answer :

```
string = '76 977'
print(sum([int(x) for x in string.split()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        print('Enter string of numbers : ')
    
    a = list(input())
    print('\nThis is character list of entered string : ')
    print(a)
    numbers = []
    num = 0
    
    for x in a:
        # ord() is used to get ascii value
        # of character ascii value of 
        # digits from 0 to 9 is 48 to 57 respectively.
        if(ord(x) >= 48 and ord(x) <= 57):
            #this code is used to join digits of 
            #decimal number(base 10) to number
            num = num*10
            num = num+int(x)
        elif num>0 :
            # all numbers in string are stored in 
            # list called numbers 
            numbers.append(num)
            num = 0
            
    if num>=0:
        numbers.append(num)
        num = 0
        
    print('\nThis is number list : ', numbers)
    sum=0
    for num in numbers:
        # all numbers are added and and sum
        # is stored in variable called sum 
        sum = sum+num
    print('Sum of numbers = ', sum)
```

[image]

Comment: this program will select only numbers present in entered string(thought string may contain any special character) and find their sum